# Google maps for ios probleam

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am learning to develop for iOS. I am using the Google Maps API for iOS to do a map. I've putted in my project a view that I've putted in my inspector element like GMSMapView.

In my code I put this code below:

```
- (void) setMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {

    if (!mapView) {
        mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:mapView.bounds];
    }

    googleMap = mapView;

}
```

The map works but I want to set up my camera on this map. On the `viewDidLoad` function I`ve putted this code below:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:12];

self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

but the Google Maps just load this map on London I don't know why. Ths coordinates its from Sidney. I have tried `googleMap = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];` but don't works too.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You can fix it by animating to the camera position once the Map has been allocated. I added a delay before animating to the new camera position. This works.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; // Any Frame

    double delayInSeconds = 0.2;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                                longitude:151.2086
                                                                     zoom:12];

        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

    });
}
```